# Cannot annotate inherited variable issue. Best alternative

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

I have a class with a variable with validation annotation:

```
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

    public class Class_A {
      @NotNull
      private String name;

      public getName() {
        return name;
      }

    }
```

This class is used in a function:

```
    public void myFunction(Class_A aObj) {
      System.out.println(aObj.getName());
    }
```

But now, I want to conditionally use the validation. I have searched and found that there is no way to conditionally check for the validation so I figured I will have to split the Class_A into two classes, one with validation (Class_A_Val) and one without validation (Class_A_NoVal).

By doing that, I can only think of below solutions for myFunction:
1) Duplicate myFunction, one for each class (Code duplication)
2) Create an abstract class with abstract method getName() and make other two classes inherit this abstract class so I can call myFunction(Abstract_Class_A)
3) Create an interface with method getName() and make other two classes implement this interface so I can call myFunction(Interface_Class_A)

Which is considered to be the best way and why? I am leaning towards #2.
Is there any other way to implement this?
Is there a way to annotate an inherited variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the annotations by using xml configuration. More information [here](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#d0e5811).